# write a recursive function to count the number of items in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion, count

I'm trying to count the numbers of items that are in an array using the recursive function on Python and I tried to code this using the count function when returning but Python seems to not recognize the count function I don't really know what can I do to fix it.

```
def countlist(list):
  if list == []:
    return 0
  else:
    return count(list[1:])
```

Comment: Nothing is recursive if you are calling _another_ function instead of your own anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The count function is part of the List functions.
To call it you have to use it like MyList.count(elem).

To count the number of each element in a list you could create a set from the list.
Sets in Python are immutable and can only contain one occurence of each element.

You could then count the elements in your list from the element in your set using list comprehension.